# Android Wear: Wi-Fi Scan No Results

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Whenever I try to use a Wi-Fi Scan for Android Wear, I always get no results from the scan. The code that I use works for my mobile device, but with Android Wear, it always returns an empty list. Code is as follows:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setAmbientEnabled();

    mContainerView = (BoxInsetLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mClockView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clock);

    test = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (test.isWifiEnabled() == false)
    {
        test.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
            {
                Log.w("myApp", "received");
                List<ScanResult> results = test.getScanResults();
                int j = 0;
                int myArray1[] = new int[results.size()];
                String myArray2[] = new String[results.size()];
                for (ScanResult result : results) {
                    //toPrint+= " " + result.BSSID  + " " + result.level + "\n";
                    myArray1[j] = result.level;
                    myArray2[j] = result.BSSID;
                    j++;
                    if (j > 20) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Button test2;
                test2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tLight);
                test2.setText("Test: " + Integer.toString(results.size()));
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0x12345);
    }
    test.startScan();
}
```

The following permissions are also enabled in the manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Interesting. You may not be able to do so, since the Android Wear device uses the connected Phone as the conduit for wifi connection. Instead, you should connect the wearable via Wear.NodeApi with GoogleApiClient to the paired phone, and request from the phone this information to transer via Wear.DataApi. I can provide a coded detailed answer if necessary

Comment: I am using a 2nd generation Moto 360 which has wifi capabilities separate from the phone. I am able to connect to the wifi directly from my watch, but doing a wifi scan through the code always returns an empty list despite this. I will try going through the phone instead, even though it is not ideal..